# Why does the "active" tab not consider comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, recent-activity

The [*active* questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) shows questions where edits being made or answers are added but not when comments are added/updated.

I know that comments are *second-class citizens*. But often the real activity on a question is in form of comments.

Why does the active tab not consider comments?

Comment: The [Interesting tab](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) does that somehow...

Answer (score 3):

Because it would be too dynamic to be useful.

At any given time a huge number of comments are being made in comparison to posts or edits. The relative usefulness of these is vastly lower and usually does not warrant new eyeballs on an issue.

Comment: But they are relevant in terms of indicating active questions.

Comment: @MilindR Not really in any meaningful way. At least 90% of comments are probably irrelevant in terms of representing a change to site content that needs to attract eyeballs for review. "+1, great answer" and "What have you tried?" do not warrant review from anyone but the person that got pinged because it was their post. In other words, comments are more indicative of active users rather that active posts, which is not what that tab is for.

Comment: Ah yes. Well in SU comments are used to give new info for troubleshooting cases. So there it does mean something has changed in the question.

Comment: @MilindR Then you are using comments wrong on SU! Extra info should be edited in to questions (ideally by the OP) if it is relevant to anybody trying to answer and only put in comments if it is only relevant as a reply to one other commenter. _Comments should request clarification or more info, but those things should be provided by edits to the question?_

Comment: I sort of knew this, but i guess it feels more natural to give more info in comments. Editing makes the question lose the context sometimes. This is one way in which SU is suboptimal for troubleshooting questions.